# Help Identifying Capacitor

Tags: capacitor, ac, components, snubber

I was given the following capacitor by a spare parts shopkeeper when I asked for a polypropylene capacitor (to be used in RC snubber circuit for a mains load).

[image]

Can someone confirm this is the right kind? Will be connecting this is series with a resistor across a mains (230v) inductive load.

**UPDATE**

Looking through google images by searching he marking on the capacitor, it seems it could be either of the ones below

- Polystyrene Film
- Polyester Film
- Metalized Polyester Film
- Polypropylene

From the images I've seen, the Polypropylene ones carry a 'PP' mark on them. Either the one I have is not a Polypropylene or it's a cheap one with no markings.

Looks like I'll have to bite the dust and get a new properly marked one.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like 100 nF, 1 kV.

The value is indicated by "104".  That's a decimal floating point format commonly used with capacitors like this.  The first two digits are the value in pF, and the last digit the power of 10 to multiply the value by.  "104" therefore means 10 x 10<sup>4</sup> pF = 100,000 pF = 100 nF.

Comment: I think the main issue that the OP has is not the value of the capacitor but the kind of it, and if it is the proper type for his intended use.

Comment: In other words: Is is polypropylene, and will it be OK for 230VAC?